# How to get a timestamp from Firebase? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the current timestamp from Firebase?
I found some methods, but they are all based on: write to database (ServerValue.TIMESTAMP), then read it. But it's not what I need, because it use additional resources. Also I've tried using System.currentTimestamp(), but its can be manipulated by the user. Is there any other ways? Maybe there is a cloud function to do so?

Comment: why do you need to get timestamp from firebase ????  Can You explain how value of System.currentTimestamp() can be manipulated ??? Explain your question so that I can help you with your issue

Comment: @AnujKumar Simply change the time and date in the phone settings and check what `System.currentTimestamp()` will give you.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own cloud function. Here is a very short example:

```
exports.currentTime = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send({"timestamp":new Date().getTime()})
})
```

You can host this firebase cloud function and get the server timestamp which a user will not be able to affect.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, It's still be the timestamp from the user phone.

Comment: No it is not. You have to call this cloud function every time you need to access current timestamp. Its like android app will call your server and then your server will give you the latest timestamp. Let me know if you need help with the android code